# Arctium lappa (greater burdock) plant

Tags: translation, culture, learning, terminology, science

Good day. Many of us know that plant called **Arctium lappa**. AKA **greater burdock**. You know, that thing that sticks to your clothes. Here's the **Wikipedia** link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arctium_lappa But as usual, translating something like that to **Esperanto** through **Google Translate** or dictionaries is... hell. **Bab.la** suggests **arktio** or **lapo**. Which... I can't find in any other online translators / dictionaries. **Google Translate** suggests **pli granda bardoko**. Which looks like a basic word-to-word translation without context. Can anyone help me to find a proper term, please? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Arctium lappa* (*greater burdock*) in Esperanto is ***lapo*** (see [PIV](https://vortaro.net/#lapo), [ReVo](https://www.reta-vortaro.de/revo/dlg/index-2d.html?q=lapo), [Vikipedio](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lapo), [English Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=lapo&oldid=65796714#Esperanto)).